# How to calculate in SQL

Tags: sql, sum, subquery

How to calculate in SQL

```
SELECT NO 
     , SUM(COST)*1.05 
  FROM TR 
 WHERE NO in (SELECT NO FROM USERS)  
   AND TR.TYPE = 'A' 
    OR TR.TYPE = 'B' 
 GROUP 
    BY NO
```

I would like to calculate the COST:

- `WHEN TR.TYPE IS A` I want to add to the total cost.
- `WHEN TR.TYPE IS B` I want to subtract the cost value from the total.

```
TR_TABLE
NO,COST,TYPE
1,1000,A
1,500, B
1,200, A
2,100, A
```

```
Ideal
No1  COST  700
No2  COST  100
```

Comment: @puss . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want a conditional expression within the aggregation function:

```
select 
    no,
    sum(case when type = 'A' then cost else -cost end) * 0.25 as fuyogaku 
from tr 
where 
    tr.type in ('A', 'B') 
    and exists (select 1 from users u where u.no = c.card_no)
group by no
```

Note that I rewrote the `in` condition as an `exists` condition - both are equivalent here, but `exists` usually scales better when there is a large number of rows in the subquery.